# Многоуровневое меню Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, menu

Нужно многоуровневое меню, которое будет выводиться из БД.
Структура пока такая. Есть общий шаблон:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  @yield('meta')
  @yield('staticlinks')
  @yield('pagescss')

<title>@yield('tittle')</title>
</head>
<body>
  @include('inc.header')
  @yield('catalog')
  @yield('content')
  @include('inc.footer')
  @yield('staticjs')
  @yield('pagesjs')
</body>
</html>
```

`header` находится в отдельном файле и подключается через `@include`.
Проблема в том, что все решения, которые я видел в сети , сделаны для одностраничных сайтов. Они добавляются роут аля `Route::get('/', 'MainController@index');`. А это же обычный шаблон, на который есть ссылка. У меня на `header`, `catalog` и `footer` нет ссылки, это подключаемые, встроенные вьюхи.
И на этом я застрял. Если и пытался делать какие то извращенные способы и писал бред(как мне показалось) типо `Route::get('catalog', 'MainController@catalog');` и в котроллере какой нибудь запрос из БД, то Laravel все время жаловался, что в шаблоне `header.blade.php` не определена переменная (например $catalog). Есть у кого то идеи как же реализовать это многоуровневое меню?

P.S. так для справки, в таблице `menus` поля `id`, `name`, `url`, `parent_id` и `img`.

Модель `Menu`:

```
protected $table = 'menus';

public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Menu', 'parent_id');
}

public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Menu', 'parent_id');
}
```

В контроллере пытался такую выборку сделать, но что возвращать, если на catalog ссылки то нет:

```
public function catalog(){
$catalog= Menu::with('children')->where('parent_id','=',0)->get();
    return view('inc.catalog',['catalog'=>$catalog]);}
```

В роуте соответственно: `Route::get('catalog', 'MainController@catalog');`

Ну и в самой вьюхе :

```
<div class='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
     <li class='has-sub'><a><span>Каталог</span></a>
      <ul>
        @foreach($catalog as $item)
         <li class='has-sub'><a href="/{{ $item->url }}"><img class="catalogimg" src="/img/jpg&png/categories/{{ $item->title}}"><span>{{ $item->name }}</span></a>
          <ul>
            @if($item->sub_menu->count() > 0)
            @foreach($menu->sub_menu as $sub)
             <li><a href="/{{ $sub->url }}"><img class="catalogimg" src="/img/jpg&png/categories/{{ $sub->img}}"><span>{{ $sub->title }}</span></a></li>
            @endforeach

          </ul>
            @endif
         </li>
         @endforeach
      </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Зачем подменили вопрос на "тут был вопрос" и "Удалил из за ненадобности"? На SO люди обмениваются информацией, а вы ее удалили. Кто-то придет из поиска и не поймет в чем был вопрос. Откатите назад, пожалуйста, и я вынужден ответить вопрос тревогой.

Comment: Я его удалил месяц назад, каким образом откачу?

Comment: Есть кнопка история и в ней есть "откат."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Версия **Laravel 8.x** (решение подходит для двухуровневого меню)
В общем, перерыв весь инет, взяв некоторую инфу с разных источников в том числе и с доков, нашел не сложный и рабочий метод как вывести из БД многоуровневое меню(работает для двухуровневого, для большего количества не пробовал). Объясню максимально подробно, вдруг будут смотреть новички.

Т.к. у меня меню, header и footer подключаются через `@inlude` сделать стандартным методом через контроллер, передав во вьху переменную, не получалось. Поэтому нашел на просторах сети, в том числе и доках способ как это сделать иначе. В `laravel` предусмотрен данный функционал, называется `VIEW COMPOSERS` (не путать с пакетным менеджером `composer`).
Для начала нам нужно создать новый провайдер следующей командой:

`php artisan make:provider ComposerServiceProvider`

Добавим его сразу в масив `providers`, где нибудь в конце, который находится по адресу `config\app.php`:

```
    'providers' => [
         
         /*
         * Other Service Providers...
         */
        App\Providers\ComposerServiceProvider::class,
],
```

Далее есть 2 варианта, первый использовать чисто `колбэки`, второй это использовать `класс`.
Подробно об обоих вариантах рассмотрено тут:

https://si-dev.com/ru/blog/laravel-view-composers.

Я использовал класс. Для этого нам нужно создать в директории `App\Http` папку `ViewComposers` и в ней файл `NavigationComposer.php`. Названия и локация файлов не так важна, как я понял, но я поступил как советовали авторы разных статей.
В файле `NavigationComposer.php` мы будем прописывать выборку из БД для нашей меню.
У меня она всего двухуровневая, поэтому выборка выглядит так:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\ViewComposers;

use Illuminate\View\View;
use App\Models\Menu;

class NavigationComposer
{
      public function compose(View $view)
      {
          $catalog = Menu::where('parent_id','=',NULL)->get();
          return $view->with('catalog', $catalog);
      }
}
```

Так же необходимо внести некоторые коррективы в ранее созданный нами `ComposerServiceProvider`. Он находится в `app\Providers`.И прописываем там:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use App\Models\Menu;

class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        View::composer(
            'inc.catalog', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\NavigationComposer'
        );
    }
}
```

Я скинул общую структуру, но добавить вы должны только то,что находится внутри функции `boot`. Первый аргумент это наш шаблон меню (он у меня находится в `resourses\views\inc\catalog.blade.php`), а второй этот как раз наш навигатор, где мы делаем выборку.
Так же естественно нам нужна модель и миграция.
Создаем их:

`php artisan make:model -m Menu`.

Потом находим нашу таблицу в `database\migrations`. Если вы ее создали с тем же названием что и я, то она будет называться `датасозданияcreate_menus_table.php`.
В ней достаточно прописать:

```
Schema::create('menus', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('parent_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->index();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('url');
    });
```

После запускаете миграцию `php artisan migrate`. И заполняете вашу табличку. В графе `parent_id` для категорий пропишите, например, `NULL`, а для подкатегорий `id` той категории, к которой данная подкатегория относится.
Дальше открываем модель по адресу `app\Models\Menu`(либо ваша модель с другим названием).
И прописываем зависимость:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Menu extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'menus';

        public function parent()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Menu', 'parent_id');
        }
        public function children()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Menu', 'parent_id');
        }
}
```

И теперь осталось вывести эти данные в нашей вьюехе.
Делал я следующим образом:

```
<div class='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
     <li class='has-sub'><a><span>Каталог</span></a>
      <ul>
        @foreach($catalog as $cat) <!-- Здесь выводятся категории-->
         <li class='has-sub'><a href="/{{ $cat->url }}"><img class="catalogimg" src="/img/jpg&png/categories/{{ $cat->img }}"><span>{{$cat->name}}</span></a>
          <ul>
            @foreach($cat->children as $subcat) <!-- Здесь подкатегории-->
             <li><a href="/{{ $subcat->url }}"><img class="catalogimg" src="/img/jpg&png/categories/{{ $subcat->img }}"><span>{{ $subcat->name }}</span></a></li>
            @endforeach
          </ul>
         </li>
         @endforeach
      </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Я **НЕ ЯВЛЯЮСЬ** автором данных решений, инфу брал с разных сайтов и источников и выбрал то, что подошло мне (это для справки уточнил, на всякий случай).
Надеюсь кому-то помог.

Comment: Это не совсем полноценное "Многоуровневое меню". У вас только 1 уровень вложенности. Я бы порекомендовал вам использовать [Nested Set](https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset) для дерева меню и сделать рекурсию для отображения view.

Comment: Надо будет попробовать. Я искал решение своего случая, просто решил поделиться) Не люблю сторонние библиотеки подключать, какое то подсознательное чувство, что нагружаю проект) Но для 3+ уровневой возможно ваше решение самое оптимальное.
Спасибо за совет!

Answer (score 0):

Получем все элементы меню (разделы каталога)

```
$items = Category::all();
```

И передаем эту переменную в шаблон, скажем `layout.part.tree` (с помощью `ComposerServiceProvider`)

```
@if (count($items->where('parent_id', $parent)))
    <ul>
    @foreach ($items->where('parent_id', $parent) as $item)
        <li>{{ $item->name }}
        @include('layout.part.tree', ['parent' => $item->id])
        </li>
    @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
```

Шаблон подключает себя рекурсивно, позволяя реализовать меню любого уровня вложенности. Причем, мы используем только один запрос к БД. И подключаем этот шаблон там, где нужно показать меню каталога:

```
<div id="catalog-tree">
    @include('layout.part.tree', ['parent' => 0])
</div>
```